# WCF slow to return one object but not the other

Tags: c#, wcf, performance-testing

I have one service running under IIS. I'm testing 2 different methods of gathering data to see which will be the best for us. The service class has 2 methods, they use the same object but 2 different methods for querying the data. One is linq to sql and the other is using a 3rd party web service. Within my service, the 2 methods each get the data in about 7 seconds. They are loading up the same object, they are in the same class in the service.
On the client, where I use the service to fill a grid, one gets the data back from the service in .18 seconds, the other takes 31.6 seconds. With the 2 methods working in the same amount of time in the service, why would there be suck a huge discrepancy in the client?
Here are the calls to the service in the client:

This one take 31.6 seconds:

```
var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
courseOfferingsSyn = clientsyn.GetCoursesOffered_SynergyService(SchoolDD.SelectedItem.ToString(), schoolYear,     TermCodeDD.SelectedValue).ToList();
var test = watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
Console.Write(test);
```

This one takes .188 seconds:

```
var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
courseOfferings = client.GetCoursesOffered(SchoolDD.SelectedValue, schoolYear, TermCodeDD.SelectedValue).ToList();
var test = watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
Console.Write(test);
```

The only difference between the two is one query wants the school code, and the other wants the school name.

Oh, and the binding(both use the same one):

```
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_CourseService" allowCookies="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" maxBufferSize="20000000" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxArrayLength="200000000" maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
    </binding>
```

Anyone have any ideas on what I can even look for? I'm stumped.

Comment: is your client on the same machine? Could it be just a network delay? tried to run it over many trials?

Comment: Client is on a different machine. Not a network delay because one is very fast, the other is very slow. Calling the same data from the same service.

Comment: the code for the speed test is not as valuable as method implementation. Can you include the method implementations for the specified WCF service?

Comment: is this the case every time you run the client? Try Fiddler to analyze the data being returned in raw format.

Comment: I can, they're a bit long. But I did time both of them and they each completed in approximately 7 seconds. But wait-- I tested the service on a local machine, but the client is calling the service after it has been published to a server. That could matter..

Comment: Same results when both client and service are using Localhost.

Comment: Used Fiddler, when watching the statistics I can see the time lapse is happening between ServerGotRequest and ServerBeginResponse. I'll begin researching that.

Comment: Sounds like the query is slow. Profile it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me the backend database is missing an index and that forces the database to search all records in the table.  That is the only reason I can think of why one call would be fast and the other slow...